Is ANALYZE command really needed to update statistics of Delta table?
According to documentation, whenever we write to a delta table, statistics are auto computed.
Question is - we also have the analyze table command which we can execute to manually compute statistics.
Question is - is there any use case where we need to explicitly compute statistics using analyze table, especially when any write to the delta table ends up computing statistics.
I am referring to tables well within the default limit of 32 columns for which statistics is collected by default.
Info on auto collection of stats for every write here
analyze table here
In some relation dbs, stats is by default computed only on certain conditions, but delta doc says stats is updated on every write , and that is why this question.

Can you share the code that you have tried so far?

Some scenarios where manually executing the ANALYZE TABLE command to compute statistics is necessary, even when automatic statistics are being collected are
Schema Evolution  & After Bulk Data Loading
I have created the sales_data  table as an example to query the table's extended statistics to verify the results.
You can compute statistics for specific columns in the sales_data table like below:
ANALYZE TABLE sales_data COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR COLUMNS product_name, quantity_sold;

After computing the statistics, you can query the extended statistics of the sales_data table to verify the results.
This step helps you understand the distribution of your data, which can be used for query optimization.
The below are the Query extended statistics for the product_name column & Query extended statistics for the quantity_sold column
DESC EXTENDED sales_data product_name;
DESC EXTENDED sales_data quantity_sold;

Results:
info_name   info_value
col_name    quantity_sold
data_type   int
comment NULL
min 5
max 20
num_nulls   0
distinct_count  5
avg_col_len 4
max_col_len 4
histogram   NULL


